# Does vuexfire have a problem with reactivity?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuefire, vuexfire

I thought there was a bug in vue dev tools, but now I'm wondering if vuexfire has a bug with reactivity? 
Clearly the mutations are firing ...

[image: mutations firing]

However, the state is always at 0 length at vue dev tools.

[image: State length 0]

BUT, console.log shows that it did pull down my two records from firebase

[image: Console.log shows leagues]

It also has an issue with my user details (such as name) which do **NOT** set off the reactive chain and update the getters once the data is pulled down into vuex (the object is also empty in vue dev tools, while data is shown in console.log()). Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Could you find out what the problem was? My `vuexfire` application works as long as I open Vue Devtools, then everything freezes.